# Why does Qt behave differently when executing the same 3 lines of code?

Tags: c++, qt

From the Qt GUI designer screen, a callback "on_textEdit_selectionChanged" was generated using the (Goto SLOT), (selection changed) options and 3 lines of code were put into that function as follows:

```
    void MainWindow::on_textEdit_selectionChanged() {
        QString msg = "in on_textEdit_selectionChanged";
        qDebug() << msg ;
        ui->textEdit->setText(msg);
    }
```

When triggered by a mouse click in the textEdit box the above function executes, writes the debug msg and DOES write to the ui.

When triggered by changing the selection via code in a different callback* the above function executes, writes the debug msg but it DOES NOT write to the ui.

Can someone explain this seemingly inconsistent behavior?

*Selection changed in another member function with with "ui->textEdit->selectAll()"

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that the text was changed successfully but you didn't update or refresh your ui after changing text via code, so your ui didn't reflect the change.

Comment: Adding a `qDebug() << this << ui;` might show possible differences.  Add it and try both paths, and compare

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue, here is a [minimal example](http://pastebin.com/s1rbW1s0). It works as expected, clicking the button will trigger the `selectionChanged` signal, the debug message is printed **and text is updated in the ui**.

Comment: But it is just a very bad idea to change the text in a `QTextEdit` every time the selection is changed.

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed you dont need to refresh it,  all components in a GUI are being double buffered.

Comment: @Mike  Thank you for your comments.  I recognize changing textEdit every time the selection is changed is a bad idea... just using it as a debug attempt but thank you for the heads up just in case.

Answer (score 0):

---

@infixed 's debug line suggestion has revealed the root of my problem.  The "this" address and the "ui" addresses are different when called from the gui callback vs my member function callback.

```
    qDebug() << "functionName this = " << this  << "ui = " << ui;
```

Suspect my my SIGNAL/SLOT connection is the problem but not sure how to fix it.  I have :

```
   connect (this, SIGNAL (showdata_signal()), this, SLOT(showdata_slot()));
```

in the constructor and:

```
    void MainWindow::display_that_data(){ //public function called 
        qDebug() << "display_that_data this = " << this  << "ui = " << ui;
        emit showdata_signal();
    }

    void MainWindow::showdata_slot() {
        QString msg = " in showdata_slot";
        qDebug() << "showdata_slot this = " << this  << "ui = " << ui;
        msg = "manual selection change";
        qDebug() << msg ;
        ui->lineEdit_3->setText(msg);
        ui->tlm_vals->selectAll();
        msg = "manual selection done";
        qDebug() << msg ;
    }

    void MainWindow::on_tlm_vals_selectionChanged() {
        static int i =0;
        QString msg = "in selectionChanged" + QString::number(i);
        qDebug() << "selectionChanged this = " << this  << "ui = " << ui;
        qDebug() << msg ;
        ui->lineEdit_2->setText(msg);
        i++;
    }
```